# Mongoose Schemea MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm building my first web app in the MEAN stack and am running into a little trouble with Mongoose. I pulled my code almost entirely from examples, and tried everything I found suggested on similar questions, but I still get the same error:

```
MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "./models/Tests".
Use mongoose.model(name, schema)
    at Mongoose.model (/Users/goldru/design-data/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:332:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/goldru/design-data/routes/index.js:16:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/goldru/design-data/app.js:12:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/goldru/design-data/bin/www:7:11)
```

Code:

app.js:

```
//connect to db; require models
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/design-data-test');
var Test = require('./models/Tests');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
```

Tests.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var TestSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String
});

mongoose.model('test', TestSchema);
```

index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

 /*GET test page.*/
router.get('/test', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('test', { title: 'Express' });
});

//set up routes
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Test = mongoose.model('./models/Tests');

router.get('/test', function(req, res, next) {
    Test.find(function(err, tests) {
        if(err) {
          return next(err);
        }

        res.json(tests);
    });
});

router.post('/test', function(req, res, next) {
    var test = new Test(req.body);

    Test.save(function(err,post) {
        if(err) {
            return next(err);
        }

        res.json(test);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You name the model `test`:

```
mongoose.model('test', TestSchema);
```

So if you want to refer to it by name, you have to use the same name:

```
var Test = mongoose.model('test');
```

I would suggest renaming the model name to `Test`, which is Mongoose convention (not a requirement, though). I would also export it from your model file:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var TestSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Test', TestSchema);
```

Comment: @tobertklep: How to implement your concept for dynamically created schema model?

Comment: @PappaS what do you mean with "dynamically created"?

Comment: Can you check this Q:  six216642six

Comment: You have solution?